# Testflight invitation email's button not clickable

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect, testflight

I have added my application to the iTunes Connect and allowed the application to go Testflight Beta testing. However, when I tried to send the invitation email to the internal tester, the email, which should contains a button to open the URL from the Testflight app appears to be not clickable, and when I tried to right click to get the hyperlink, it does not have it. The button become looks like this,

[image: Button with problem]

As far as I am concerned, the button should actually looks like this,

[image: Correct button]

I have tried to remove the internal tester from the Users & Roles section, re-adding the user as internal tester, as well as remove the tester role, adding it back again to get a new invitation email, but all the emails have this same issue.

Any ways so that I can get the button back to the usual one?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using default mail app in iPhone? I believe if we use other apps i.e. GMail app you will get this non clickable button. If we use default mail app it should work.

Comment: @Chandan005 I am using the default in email. but previously I have tried using the email on my pc and forward the email to my iPhone which has a different email account (and even not in the internal test list), I would still be able to click the button. It just so happen that it just recently started to send me invitation emails of not clickable button.

Comment: @mfl are you still seeing this issue? I can't figure out for the life of me what's causing it. As a potential workaround, if I open the original email (not a forwarded version) in an internet browser, the button works and then I can see the application in TestFlight at least.

Comment: @WilliamCorncobDecker yes I am still having this issue. I cant really try your workarounds as my original email is open in Outlook, making me unable to open them in a browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after some time, I did tried on the alternative mentioned by @WilliamCorncobDecker that I eventually opened the email in a web browser. However, in my case, the button is still not clickable. So, what I did was to view the page source and get the invitation URL and send to URL to my device.

Open the URL from the device, and it's working fine now.